# Tableau Lookup Function

Tags: excel, tableau-api

How can I match duplicates in products under the same column in tableau - this is my attempt in tableau:

```
IF([CoreProd_ID] = (LOOKUP([CoreProd_ID])-1)) THEN
([Actual Revision Date]-(LOOKUP([Actual Revision Date]-1)))
ELSE
END
```

The error message is a syntax error, maybe you are missing an identifier - how can I fix this?

This is the formula I have in excel: `=IF(A2=A3, AI2-AI3, ” “)` - Thank you!

Comment: Your missing a comma in the LOOKUP formula. Should be LOOKUP(ATTR([CoreProd_ID],-1). Even with the syntax change, I'm not convinced it'll work, it depends on how you lay out your data.

Comment: The way you go about things in Tableau is sometimes different than Excel. I suspect the solution to what you are trying to do will not involve the LOOKUP() function. That is a table calc function. Get the basic things working before you start to learn about table calcs.

Comment: Thank you all - @AlexBlakemore, do you recommend anything that could help me learn more about functions in tableau?

Comment: Thank you, @AndyTARSols - Appreciate it!

Comment: @CatalinaTocasuchil To learn about functions and calculations in Tableau, start with the on-line help in Tableau, the free training on their web site, prior Tableau conference videos, blogs mentioned in “Best of the Tableau Web” and the book “Learning Tableau …” by Joshua Milligan. You can also learn from Tableau’s YouTube channel, Tableau Public, Tableau Tip Tuesday and Workout Wednesday, experimenting with the sample workbooks, and taking the e-learning from Tableau. Be sure to understand aggregation, dimensions, measures and order-of-operations